# SQL Query Distinct Binary replace with date column

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have multiple meals in my database and there are inside a text type. Sometime I have a backspace sometime no. E.g

```
Meal 1
hamburger1

Meal 2
hamburger1
hamburger2
hamburger3
hamburger4

Meal 3
Pizza1
Pizza2

Meal 4
hamburger1
hamburger2
hamburger3
hamburger4  <- with whitespace
```

I need to distinct this column (named description) including whitespace. As you can see Meal2 and 4 are the same so I have to distinct them. Then I did this mysql query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT(BINARY replace(description,' ','')), description FROM meals
```

It works. But when I add the date column, the distinct doesn't work anymore. Maybe date is a mysql keyword and this broke my query ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT(BINARY replace(description,' ','')), description, date, type FROM meals
```

How can I make it works with this column named date ?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? I'm not sure, but I suspect that your date column makes each occurrence distinct from the others (i.e. will return as separate rows in your result set).

Comment: The problem is that the distinct is ignored and I have a normal select with all rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DISTINCT` is not a function, even though you have used parentheses to make it look like it's a function.

`DISTINCT` is a *query modifier*. It always applies to *all* the columns in your select-list. If any column is different, the whole row counts as distinct. The parentheses you used are actually meaningless.

Example: The following rows are distinct from each other, because the date is different from those on other rows, even though the first two columns are the same.

```
a  1  2016-10-20
a  1  2016-10-21
a  1  2016-10-22
```

If you want to reduce your query result to those rows with distinct values in one particular column, use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT TRIM(description) AS description, MAX(date), MAX(type) 
FROM meals
GROUP BY description
```

(Tip: the `TRIM()` function is a more convenient way of doing what you were doing with REPLACE())

The other columns, date and type, should be kept inside group-aggregate functions. I've used MAX() in this example. If you don't do this, and the group has multiple rows with different values for date and type, it'll choose one of the rows sort of arbitrarily. This ambiguous kind of query throws an error by default in MySQL 5.7 and later.